# Canvas image not display when load

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here i am trying to make circle using multiple arc shape. like following:

```js
var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 6;
var ctx;

var leftValue=275;
var topValue=300; 
    
var wheelImg = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwXlF.png";

function drawWheelImg()
{
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   if(canvas.getContext)
 {
  var outsideRadius = 260;
  var textRadius = 217;
  var insideRadius = 202;

  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

  for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
  {
   var angle = startAngle + i * arc;

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
   ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
   ctx.shadowBlur=3;
   ctx.shadowColor="#A47C15";
   ctx.stroke();
   ctx.closePath();
   
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(leftValue + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
      topValue + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
   ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
   var imgName = wheelImg;
   var img = new Image();
   
   img.src = wheelImg;
   ctx.drawImage(img,-44, -25,50,40);
   ctx.restore();
  }
   }
} 



function spin()
{
 drawWheelImg();
}

drawWheelImg();
```

```html
<button class="btnSpin" onclick="spin();">Spin</button>

<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="580"></canvas>
```

**Problem:**

Now, issue is when page load i call function which draw circle using arc and draw image in to the arc. But that not working.

And if i call same function on button click then it works and display image.

I found lot but didn't get the solution. Don't know why image not display on load.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: any console errors in your browser?

Comment: Did you call the function using the $(window).ready or onload event?

Comment: You have to wait for the image to load befor you can render it. Use `image.onload` to get when the image has loaded or check `image.complete `

Comment: @Lal no. there is no error in console .

Comment: @Will no. that function is called when page load automatically. that's why circle is draw. But image not load.

Comment: @Blindman67 i do that but image not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that you should have to wait until the image is loaded before actually draw it.

My best option, in order to get your code working, is to wrap all the canvas drawing into an image.onload function, because in this way you can be sure it will be rendered once you start actually drawing on it.

I post you the code on a working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4mtz2qSb4KmwltXPzYvP?p=preview)

```js
var startAngle = 0;
var arc = Math.PI / 6;
var ctx;

var leftValue = 275;
var topValue = 300;

var wheelImg = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwXlF.png";

function drawWheelImg() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var imgName = wheelImg;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = wheelImg;

        img.onload = function() {
            var outsideRadius = 260;
            var textRadius = 217;
            var insideRadius = 202;

            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                var angle = startAngle + i * arc;

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, insideRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(leftValue, topValue, outsideRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
                ctx.shadowColor = "#A47C15";
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();

                ctx.save();
                ctx.translate(leftValue + Math.cos(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius,
                    topValue + Math.sin(angle + arc / 2) * textRadius);
                ctx.rotate(angle + arc / 2 + Math.PI / 2);
                ctx.drawImage(img, -44, -25, 50, 40);
                ctx.restore();
            }
        }
    }
}

drawWheelImg();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this will work. I will implement and let you know.